# Android CTS doesn't executes tests

Tags: android, command, facebook-android-sdk, cts

I'm able to execute a test from command line for example 
run cts -c android.display.cts.DisplayTest the result says that XML test result file generated at 2018.05.31_15.33.30. Passed 0, Failed 0, Not Executed 0. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a device connected via `adb`.

Example:

```
adb devices
```

should have an output like this:

List of devices attached
    10.1.1.113:5555 device

also in the `cts-tf >` this command should list the devices

```
l d
Serial               State   Allocation  Product      Variant      Build            Battery  
10.1.1.113:5555      ONLINE  Allocated   product      product      2018030000          100
```

should output:

I you don't have any device connected, you should follow this steps, I put here the step for connecting on Ethernet since is more scale-able.

```
adb connect 10.1.1.113:5555
```

and on the android device:

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
stop adbd
start adbd
```

if you don't know the IP on the android device:

```
ip a
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is no test present. Use proper CTS command to run tests

from android-O (8.0):

Command:
run cts -m < Module Name >

To get List of modules:
l m

https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/run#ctsv2_reference

Till android-N:

Command:
run cts -p < Module Name >
run cts -c < class name > -m < method name >

To get List of modules:
list packages

https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/run#cts_reference

Answer (score 0):

This happens if specific package, class, or test is missing :

For example, 
`run cts -m Gesture --test android.gesture.cts.GestureTest#testGetStrokes`

In the above example see if "GestureTest#testGetStrokes" is proper.

Refer [here](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/run#ctsv2_reference)